# Realtek SD/MMC card reader not working

Tags: 18.04, sd-card, card-reader

I have System76 Laptop Lemur that I had bought about a year ago. (A lemur) with ubuntu 17.04 on it. I recently installed ubuntu 18.04. I have a integrated sd/mmc card reader that does not pick up the card when I insert it. When I type in `lspci` I get:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Skylake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 520 (rev 07)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port (rev f1)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d11 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8411B PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
01:00.1 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 12)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 (rev 81)
```

So it looks like the Unassigned class is the card reader. I know there are questions like this,but not of the solutions work. I hope someone can help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question:
I tried rebooting with the card in,and it worked.
I also ran apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
Seems to bug in the kernel
Hope it is fixed in next update.

Comment: Please click on the checkmark at left under the u[/down carts to show you accept your answer, which makes it easier for folks to sift through questions to see those with answers which worked.

Comment: Same issue on my Lenovo. I have read that this buck has been existing since kernel version 4.2 .